# how to clean NSUserDefault while my app is crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I want to clean my UserDefault while my app is crashing or crashed,how to do it.is there any APIs for me from Apple?

Comment: There is nothing built-in to detect a crash. Use something like PLCrashReporter for that.

Comment: Perhaps this is an indication that using `NSUserDefaults` is not a good solution (hint: is usually isn't). Are you saving user defaults?

Comment: You could override every available method of quitting in the app delegate protocol to set a flag that indicates you exited normally, and check it on startup...

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Why not don't crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this method delegate when crash, do something to clear NSUserDefaults or others actions.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application 
{
   // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```